# Adding Servlet Filter to existing deployed applicaton on WebLogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, servlet-filters

We are running Oracle EPM as an application under webLogic and are looking at the best way to restrict access at certain times (for maintenance etc).  I think a servlet filter would be a neat way to do this, but not sure exactly how I would go about deploying it after development.

The application is already deployed automatically by Oracle installation tools.  I have found the EAR used, but I think it would be messy updating that and re-deploying it.  Another option would be to modify the expanded EAR under the temp directory, but I think that is even worse.

Any idea how I might add a servlet filter to this pre-deployed application?

Comment: Do you want to take the entire EAR offline? or restrict access to a select few?

Comment: Just restrict from some users, EAR must remain online.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking to restrict access to.  Is it some specific urls while the app is being redeployed for upgrades?

Comment: We want to restrict access to application for non-admin users while some tasks (refreshing Essbase cubes) are being performed.